# Meteor Semantic-UI less compile error

Tags: meteor, semantic-ui

Im trying to use the official semantic-ui meteor package. I followed all the step to generate the folders but I got this error:

```
   While building the application:
   client\lib\semantic-ui\theme.import.less:23:10: Less compiler error:
   expected ')' got 'o'
```

I checked the file and Its this line:

```
@import (optional) "@{themesFolder}/@{site}/globals/site.variables";
```

Im not sure what is the problem but I think is something related to the (optinal).

How can i fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try removing the official Meteor less package and adding the less-autofixer Meteor package.

```
meteor add flemay:less-autoprefixer
```

This is a necessary prerequisite to the official semantic ui package.

Comment: i have it in my project

Comment: I am very sorry for suggesting the official Meteor less package. Apparently the semantic ui package requires the less autoprefixer package, which is incompatible with the official Meteor less package. Check out my edited answer to see how to install it.